# Autoplay video in using <iframe> tag?

Tags: android, html

The iframe tag is auto playing the YouTube videos( using '?autoplay=1') but it is unable to auto play the videos in MediaCore. So, how do I auto play the videos in MediaCore?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The file you want to look at is /path_to_your_mediacore_installation_dir/mediacore/mediacore/lib/players.py line 151.

```
def player_vars(self):
    """Return a python dict of vars for this player."""
    vars = {
        **'autostart': self.autoplay,**
        'height': self.adjusted_height,
        'width': self.adjusted_width,
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'image': thumb_url(self.media, 'l', qualified=self.qualified), <----- THAT, ADDED.
        'players': [
            # XXX: Currently flash *must* come first for the RTMP/HTTP logic.
            {'type': 'flash', 'src': self.swf_url()},
            {'type': 'html5'},
            {'type': 'download'},
        ],
    }
```

Remove the ** ... **